# Facebook Delete Comment API problems (#200) App does not have sufficient permission for this action for remove comments

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I Logged-in with user that I am facebook pages administrator. I write api to delete spam comments in posts by use this method.

```
$scope.deleteComments = function (commentID) {
    if (confirm("Confirm Delete Comments")) {
        FB.api(
                "/" + commentID,
                "DELETE",
                function (response) {
                    console.log(response, commentID);
                    if (response && !response.error) {
                        /* handle the result */

                    }
                }
        );
    }
};
```

I followed instructions from "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/comment". Before I use Facebook API I given and Permission with this code.

```
$scope.triggerLogin = function () {
        FB.login(function () {
            $scope.checkLoginState();
        }, {
            scope: "public_profile, publish_pages, manage_pages"
        });
    };
```

so that while I use deleteComments() function I get error object from facebook like this

> - error: Object
> - code: 200
> - message: "(#200) App does not have sufficient permission for this action"
> - type: "OAuthException"

Does anyone know how to fixed this problems, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely not using a Page Token, right now it looks like you are using a User Token. You MUST use a Page Token to delete comments. Generate a Page token by using the `/me/accounts` endpoint (or `/page-id?fields=access_token` for a specific Page) and use it in the API call:

```
FB.api(
    '/' + commentID,
    'DELETE',
    {access_token: 'your-page-token'},
    function (response) {
        console.log(response, commentID);
        if (response && !response.error) {
            /* handle the result */

        }
    }
);
```

More information about Tokens and how to generate them:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Long shot. But is this still working for you? I still get the token error using this.